# commands to make ethernet interfaces up down using ip command

Tags: ip, ifconfig

I was using following commands to `up` the devices

```
# ifconfig p1p1:1 10.250.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
# ifconfig p1p1:2 10.251.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
# ifconfig p1p1:3 10.252.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
```

I don't have `ifconfig` installed currently on a new device, but have `ip` command

I can use `ip addr` command to see the ip addresses of my system

what are the equivalent commands  of `ifconfig ... up` using command `ip`

`ip link show` output is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: p1p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ba:e7:ae:ed:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: p1p2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ba:e7:ae:ed:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:aa:3e:25:47:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: em2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:aa:3e:25:47:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example will assume that your network card's name is `eth0`.

To bring up interface: `ip link set eth0 up`

To bring down interface: `ip link set eth0 down`

Comment: Barnabas, I also need to use `p1p1`, these are for connecting three different machines using internal ips

Comment: replace `eth0` with `p1p1` if your interface's name is `p1p1`

Comment: if i use `ip link set p1p1:1 10.250.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 up` i am getting _Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "10.250.0.0" is a garbage._

Comment: This command is for putting interface up or down. To add an IP there is another command: `ip address add IPADDR/CIDR dev IFACE`. Also note you don't need any ":1" aliases, ip supports multiple addresses without all that crap.

Comment: Your original question just asked how to bring interfaces up, did not specify that you would like to set the IP address and net mask in the same command. In order to specify the IP address, subnet mask information you should take a look at the netplan config file and setup your networking details there, then bring the interfaces up. Check this link for details: https://danielmiessler.com/study/manually-set-ip-linux/

Comment: I want to point out explicitely `ip` from `iproute2` is not a drop-in replacement for `ifconfig`. It uses completely different approaches. It is a functional replacement for  `ifconfig`, `route`, `brctl`, `vconfig`, `iptunnel`, `tunctl` and some other commands, it can do everything these can do combined and more, but command line syntax is different.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov you will have to excuse me for for being a noob , i am really new with network stuff i made command as per you ex: `ip address add 10.253.0.0 p1p1` where should i specify netmask?

Comment: I depicted that in my other comment. Usually you specify netmask length in CIDR format, like this: `10.253.0.1/16` (for the mask 255.255.0.0). BTW, your IP address/netmask pairs are wrong and can't be assigned to an interface, because they all have zeros in host part. I wrote ".1" address in my example here to reflect that. Try to use any online IP calculator out there to get a list of allowed addresses, calculate netmasks, CIDR mask length and so on. // You probably learning from ancient books or manuals. For Linux try to read LARTC, which is modern enough — https://lartc.org/howto/